# Install Intel motherboard drivers or just leave those from Windows Update?

Tags: windows, drivers, motherboard, windows-update, intel-core-i7

Do you install Intel motherboard drivers?

Or just skip it and leave those from Windows Update?

Are there any benefits?

F.i. here's a ss of drivers WU installed on my new-ish laptop (6th gen i7)
[Windows Update drivers screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/562nP.png)

Comment: I use the Intel tool to update drivers.

Answer (score 1):

The [Intel Driver Assistant](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/intel-driver-support-assistant.html) automates finding the correct new drivers for your CPU and chip set, and has many drivers and patches Windows Update will not. There have been significant microcode patches for security purposes, so, yes, I would recommend it.

PS:  Intel has not made consumer motherboards for years.

Comment: Its a laptop, I doubt it is an Intel board.

Comment: And, I agree, _Moab_.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't have the expertise in motherboards and their drivers, people who are experts when it comes to NDIS drivers (at least at my company) are saying that INBOX drivers are using most conservative settings available to maximize stability, usually at the cost of performance. So even in cases where INBOX and OEM provided drivers are the same binaries, the OEM provided drivers usually perform better - because they use more performance optimized settings.

So yes - update.

Disclosure - I work for Intel. I present my personal opinion here based on "tribal knowledge" in my organization.